# How can I be notified of updates on nvidia-current drivers?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, nvidia

Is there anyway to subscribe to updates on the nvidia-current drivers in Ubuntu Natty and the support for the nVidia 7300 / 7400 series. I don't want to upgrade to a system that does not support my card or at least have some backward compatibility. And even though I will check out how Fedora handled it later in the month, I really don't feel like leaving my favourite distro ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking nvidia forum for announcement: http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=122606
When support for 7300 series & X.org 1.10 will be declared, add **ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates** to your system's Software Sources, and update. Updates usually land to x-swat very fast, in 1-2 days.